# Shall I use progressive or simple in that case

Tags: progressive-aspect, past-simple

Shall I say

> In 1789 people **were not wearing** watches because they did not exist.

OR

> In 1789 people **did not wear** watches because they did not exist.

i think the second one is a better because it is general truth

Comment: Yes, I agree with your assessment. The progressive would be appropriate in a sentence like "I wasn't wearing my watch because I was taking a shower". Do note the little bit of ambiguity in your sentence though... some people may read the last part as _because the people did not exist_.

Comment: As an aside, I would use **should** in posing the question: "**Should I use Past Progressive or.."

Comment: It might better be described as a general untruth. Pendant watches have been worn since the 16th century, and pocket watches since the 17th. It is only the wristwatch which did not exist in 1789.

Comment: P.S. "*this* case" — reserve "that" for information already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think both the sentences are grammatically correct. They express a temporary state of a  fact in the past.

The use of the past continuous puts more emphasis on this state than that of the past simple.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, but the latter is more likely and useful in more contexts. As you said, it's a general statement and that makes sense for a claim about "people" in general.

As Khan wrote, the progressive insists on an ongoing state. Usually we use the progressive because something else is happening simultaneously.

So you might say: "The sky suddenly clouded over and it began to rain sooner than anyone could have expected. **No one was carrying an umbrella** — the weather had been so fine from the morning till five minutes before the downpour."

But that's a specific event. I find it hard to come up with a case where I would use it for a general truth. Everything I can think of is either a stretch or would be better served by the simple past anyway.